# Can I do a in-process background task in a WPF app in Desktop Bridge

Tags: wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge

I've used Desktop Bridge (Project Centennial) to convert my WPF application into the UWP world. In the converted app I'm going to use a background task. It would be very conveniant if I could run it in in-process but as far as I understand it is not possible to do in the WPF process?

Correct? Or is there some magic trick I could use?

Comment: How about `BackgroundWorker: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx`?

Comment: A BackgroundWorker is not really the same as a UWP BackgroundTask. A BackgroundTask can be invoked by a number of system events also when the actual app is not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use an [app service that runs in the same process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/convert-app-service-in-process) as its host *UWP* app, but a WPF application has a different `Application` class than the `Windows.UI.Xaml` UWP `Application` class that has no `OnBackgroundActivated` method to be called when the app service is invoked.

So you should either use a background task that runs in a separate process or convert your application into a pure UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

The background task needs to run out-of-proc with the WPF app.

You can find a sample here: https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/JourneyAcrossTheBridge_Build2017Edition/Step3